# Issue Reading Delta Tables from S3 in Databricks (_delta_log)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, delta-lake, aws-databricks

I'm encountering a challenge when attempting to read certain Delta tables from an S3 bucket in Databricks. My goal is to load Delta tables into Databricks, and while some tables like `table_1` load successfully, others such as `table_2` produce the following error:

> AnalysisException: Incompatible format detected.
>
> You are trying to read from SECOND_DATALAKE/table_2/ using Delta, but there is no transaction log present. Check the upstream job to make sure that it is writing using format("delta") and that you are trying to read from the table base path.

I believe the reason behind this issue is that my AWS Glue job fails to generate the `_delta_log` folder for heavy tables like `table_2`.

Below is the code snippet from my AWS Glue job:

```scala
table_to_copy = 'TABLE_2'
try:
    # Script generado para node Oracle SQL
    OracleSQL_node1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        connection_type="oracle",
        connection_options={
                "url": 'jdbc:oracle:thin://@datalake.eu-west-3.rds.amazonaws.com:10523:NAME1', 
                "user": username,
                "password": password,
                "dbtable": 'SCHEMA.' + table_to_copy,
            },
        transformation_ctx="OracleSQL_node1",
    )
    
    # Convertir a DataFrame
    dataFrame = OracleSQL_node1.toDF()
    
    # Escribir en formato Delta
    dataFrame.repartition(10) \
        .write.format('delta') \
        .mode('overwrite') \
        .save("SECOND_DATALAKE" + table_to_copy)  
        
    logger.info(f"{table_to_copy} was copied to the Delta Lake correctly")
except Exception as e:
    logger.error(f"Error copying {table_to_copy} to Delta Lake: {str(e)}")

job.commit()
spark.stop()
```

How can I address this problem and ensure that the `_delta_log` folder is generated appropriately for all tables, irrespective of their size?

AWS Glue job is responsible for extracting data from Oracle and writing it to S3 in Delta format.
The error occurs specifically for tables perceived as "heavy" by AWS Glue.

How do I optimize the AWS Glue job to ensure the generation of the `_delta_log` folder for all tables?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem too.

> But I can't give you working sample.
> Because I'm working with [OSS delta lake](https://delta.io/)(=Linux foundation delta lake)

This link([Create a table - DataFrameWriter API](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-batch.html#create-a-table)) might be helpful to understand what is different using metastore or not.

Anyway, let's try to add `/` to your path as below.

```scala
dataFrame.repartition(10) \
    .write.format('delta') \
    .mode('overwrite') \
    //.save(    "SECOND_DATALAKE" + table_to_copy) //not work
    .save("/" + "SECOND_DATALAKE" + table_to_copy)
```

AFAIK, This will work.
If your storage on s3, refer to [sample code link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-format-delta-lake.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-format-delta-lake-write)

```
// Example: Example: Create a Delta Lake table from a DataFrame
// and register the table to Glue Data Catalog

val additional_options = Map(
  "path" -> "s3://<s3Path>"
)
dataFrame.write.format("delta")
  .options(additional_options)
  .mode("append")   // based on your needs, append/overwrite
  .partitionBy("<your_partitionkey_field>")
  .saveAsTable("<your_database_name>.<your_table_name>")
```

**Further information of Metastore**

Spark need metastore, it could be one of as below

- hive(or hive-metastore)
- AWS Glue: AWS only
- Unity Catalog: Databricks only
- Derby: Embedded or configured by yourself(good for develop)

metastore has

- Table name with its location(path on your storage) and properties.
- Schema(DB Name) with a base path; aka "spark.sql.warehouse.dir"

OK, let's take a look code again,

```scala
// save() --> a path(your path will created under spark.sql.warehouse.dir)
// You need to remember where table saved.
df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("/tmp/delta/people10m")

// saveAsTable() --> table name.
// You don't need to remember where table saved.
df.write.format("delta").saveAsTable("default.people10m")
```

So, if you are using Databricks + AWS Glue, it would be better use `saveAsTable()` with table names.

```
// This is naming of table.
{catalog_name}.{schema(or DB)_name}.{table_name}
```